# Getting id_token from Microsoft OAuth2.0

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, ngcordova

Cordova Plugin: https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth  and ionic v1

I am using a modified version of oauthWindowslive.  I am trying to get `id_token`  form the Microsoft OAuth2.0.  Since I am using the service to get some outlook calendar data I am using the following:

```
var browserRef = window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=' + clientId + "&scope=openid+profile+User.Read"  + '&response_type=token&response_mode=fragment' + '&display=touch' + '&redirect_uri=' + redirect_uri, '_blank', 'location=no,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes');
```

But if I insert `id_token+token` for the `response_type`  I cannot authenticate.  I cannot authenticate even if I try using `id_token` even if I try using it by itself.

Comment: Do you mean there is an error if you specify token as the response type? Have you enabled the implicit flow in the app manifest?

Comment: @juunas When redirected to the Microsoft account page I cannot go beyond the account login screen and cannot enter a password.  Yes, the implicit flow is enabled when client id was generated.  Do I need to do that somewhere in the ionic code as well?.

Comment: No, the manifest setting is enough. That is quite weird, is there really no error on the login screen?

Comment: No.  No errors.  I cannot go beyond the login screen.  But if remove id_token from the string then there are no problems but no id_token.  I need the id_token for refreshing the access token.

Comment: I think that `nonce` is also required .:-)

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT  It is added by the oauth.utils call. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth/master/dist/ng-cordova-oauth.js

Comment: Try to use your `tenant` instead of `common`.

Comment: But then you need tenant name - right?  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user#2-get-authorization  You need to assign a value to the tenant.  {tenant} web service call fails.

Comment: I think it may be the point. If you don't specify you tenant domain, you need to use `domain_hint` and `login _hint` .

Comment: none of this worked.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it working.   The web service is picky about two things:

1. id_token has to come before token and it should be immediately after the response_type prompt. response_type=id_token+token
2. While the documentation says it is ok to use the http://localhost/callback - in reality, it is not.  At least, on a hybrid app it has to be https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf

Interestingly enough for other Oauth services such as Google and Facebook localhost/callback works fine.  Microsoft for some reason requires special treatment.    If anyone from Microsoft is listening - please clean up and merge your identity platforms and documentation.  It should not take a developer 5 days to figure out something so trivial.